# AWS Transcode Video HLS are not been played in Offline Mode In Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming

Hi I have a HLS video which is encrypted via a AWS Transcoder.
I am able to play this (HLS Encrypted video) video from remote.
The same video(HLS Encrypted video) on download using HLS Downloader. It is not playing.
Is there any AWS Content Key Delivery Management to over Come this issue?

I Have implement offline download using AVAsset Downloader.
I not implement apple Fair Play system For Content Key Delivery Management
The video will play if it has a sync with internet for 1 second after that the internet is not required

Have used this link to implement HLS Downloader 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html

I need to download the HLS Encrypted Video using the Apple HLS Downloader and play it in offline without using any sync of internet

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: You need to add DRM for the video which you have a encrypted. or try the video with apple FairPlay protection with Azure Transocde will help you

Comment: Can you please look below question and provide solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625005/ios-playing-offline-hls-with-aes-128-encryption

Comment: I could not able to get your question. 1. Can you give the video url which your are try to download?.   2. Are your encode the video with AES 128?.   3.If you are encoded the video what transcode are using to encode video?.

Comment: My main theme is download the encrypted video content and playing in offline with out using FairPlay.
1. https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/rmp-segment/bbb-abr-aes/playlist.m3u8
2. Yes Using AES 128.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue please share any example, we are using the Brightcove zendcoder to encode the video.